# Set value in JObject using JsonPath

Tags: c#, json

I want to update a JObject with some values through their JSONPath.

For example: 
I have this JSON

```
{
    "lastname": "Butler",
    "phone": [
        123123123,
        141414
    ],
    "address": [
        {
            "addressLine1": "123",
            "addressLine2": "124"
        },
        {
            "addressLine1": "123",
            "addressLine2": "144",
            "additionalInfo": {
                "pin": 123321,
                "landmark": "landmark1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the info about the paths.

```
[
    {
        "path":"lastName",
        "value": "Travolta"
    },
    {
        "path": "phone",
        "value": [
            9999999,
            8888888
        ],
    }
    {
        "path":"address[1].addressLine2",
        "value": 123
    },
    {
        "path":"address[2]",
        "value": {
            "addressLine1": "1223",
            "addressLine2": "1242"
        }
    }
]
```

I want to update/Add the value to json object for all the paths provided using newtonsoft library. 
The nesting of the paths is not restricted, it go on n levels.

Comment: I want to actually reach that json property through the path provided and update/insert the value in existing JSON.

Comment: Does the array indices 0 based or not? Because it can be a problem to maintain them. Also, your second json isn't properly formatted

Comment: yes, it is 0 based, for path address[2] the value should be added since the address array is of size 2 currently.

Comment: If the index is 0 based, the address[2] points to 3rd element in array, which doesn't exist